# BackgroundCssClass not being applied with ModalpopupExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, modalpopupextender

I am trying to create this webpage that shows a database with a "Master-Detail" type view. To do this I am following this tutorial http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html.

The only difference is that I am not using ObjectDataSource, instead I am just using my SQL - DataBase.

Here's the problem:  When I click on the link to show the modalPopup, the BackgroundCssClass is not being applied, and the popup just shows up in the corner of the screen without changing the background and opacity.  Anyone know whats going on?

Here's the code:

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
        TR.updated TD
        {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        .modalBackground 
        {
            background-color:Gray;
            filter:alpha(opacity=70);
            opacity:0.7;
        }
    </style>
```

Modalpopup part (right above this is the gridview that shows the "Master" section of the Database, this works fine so I didn't include it.

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlReservationDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button id="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
                <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" 
                    CancelControlID="btnClose"                      
                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
                <asp:DetailsView ID="dvReservationDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="mainTable" CssClass="detailgrid"
                    GridLines="None" DefaultMode="Edit" AutoGenerateRows="false" Visible="false" Width="100%">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LabName" DataField="labName" ReadOnly="true" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Text="Hello" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Fields>
                </asp:DetailsView>
                <div class="footer">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" 
                        Text="Save" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" CausesValidation="true"
                     />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnClose" runat="server" 
                        Text="Close" CausesValidation="false" 
                    />
                </div>
                 </ContentTemplate>                
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you are using `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />` instead of `<ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" />`

here's a little example of "normal" usage, just in case

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShow_ClientSide" runat="server"
    Text="show client side" OnClientClick="return false" />
<asp:Button ID="btnShow_ServerSide" runat="server"
    Text="show server side" OnClick="btnShow_ServerSide_Click" />
<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="btnShow_ClientSide"
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" CancelControlID="btnHide_ClientSide"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black">
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide_ClientSide" runat="server"
            Text="hide client side" OnClientClick="return false" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide_ServerSide" runat="server"
            Text="hide server side" OnClick="btnHide_ServerSide_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void btnShow_ServerSide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mdlPopup.Show();
}
protected void btnHide_ServerSide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mdlPopup.Hide();
}
```

Comment: maybe you should award the bounty?

Comment: Whoops, I thought it did it once I said this was the answer.  Bounty awarded.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a completely different cause of this problem, and here's the solution, which I found on this very helpful [walk-through page](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/07/working-with-modal-popup-extender.html).

> BackgroundCssClass: The name of the CSS class which needs to be applied to the background of the popup. One thing to note here is that **if you don’t provide a CSS class then the modal popup will not function like a modal dialog** i.e. One will be able to interact with the controls in the back of the popup control, so its imperative to provide a valid CSS class name value to the BackgroundCssClass property. In the above e.g. we have defined a CSS class called “backgroundColor” in the header section of the aspx page. Please note in the CSS class definition we have applied “filter” property to make the background transparent.

I had made a typo in the .css file, which prevented reading the background style. As soon as the CSS was working, the popup became modal and had its proper background.